# Usar SQL LIKE para encontrar um número seguido por espaço

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um campo reunindo valores que são sequências de números separados por espaço e vírgula, como: "1 , 2 , 3 , 23 , 41 , 54"

Estava usando SQL dentro do PHP pra encontrar um número dentro desse campo com LIKE, mas da forma que eu fiz, se eu quisesse encontrar só 5, por exemplo, ele encontraria o 54 no campo que escrevi ali em cima, e isso estaria errado.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select nm_linha from linhas where cidades_origem like '%$cod_cidades%' and ida like '%$cod_bairros%' and cidades_destino like '%$cod_cidades2%' and ida like '%$cod_bairros2%'");
```

**cidades_origem**, **ida** e **cidades_destino** são colunas do banco; **$cod_cidades**, **$cod_cidades2**, **$cod_bairros** e **$cod_bairros2** são variáveis PHP com os números que quero encontrar.

Como posso fazer pra que a consulta busque o número em questão antecedido e seguido por um espaço, sendo que antes e depois desses espaços possa existir qualquer conteúdo (%)?

Comment: Numa solução perfeita, você tem que normalizar esse campo em outras tabelas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usa a virgula do separador para encontrar ex:> `LIKE '%, 5,%'...` neste caso o primeiro registro deveria vir antecedido por `", "` também ex:>`, 1, 2, 3,`
 Este creio que seja o método mais simples para sua forma de consulta...

Answer (score 2):

Para uma solução mais limpa, você pode utilizar a função [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) para buscar algo em uma lista, sem necessidade de altera-la:

```
select
  nm_linha
from
  linhas
where
  find_in_set($cod_cidades, replace(cidades_origem, ' ', ''))
  and find_in_set($cod_bairros, replace(ida, ' ', ''))
  and find_in_set($cod_cidades2, replace(cidades_destino, ' ', ''))
  and find_in_set($cod_bairros2, replace(ida, ' ', ''))
```

Baseado no seu exemplo de lista, utilizei o `REPLACE` somente para remover os espaços, mas se tiver a possibilidade de já guardar esses valores sem espaços já elimina esta função da sua *query*.

Aqui está um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cfdc/3/0) para você testar a solução.